# connecting zimbra desktop to exchange

Tags: windows, exchange, zimbra

I'm trying to setup Zimbra Desktop for one of our users here. No matter what I try it doesn't accept the username I put in.

I've tried:

domain\networkaccount

fqdn\networkaccount

networkaccount

first.last

(first.last as in their email address before @)

It also didn't like our wildcard cert at first so I had to force accept it, but I can't get it to auth. I'm trying the "Microsoft Exchange IMAP" and regular IMAP, neither seem to authenticate. I can't find any logs just yet which show how auth is going on the host.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have discovered a few things:

a) it helps to turn up the logs for IMAP

b) When your pre-windows 2000 login for an account does not match your exchange alias (all can be found in a domain user account profile) you need to use the following method to login:

domain\login\exchangealias

I did not need to use a FQDN, I could just use the short name of the domain. In our case our domain logins differ from exchange aliases. So far as I can tell, but I cannot test, if your pre-2000 login and exchange alias match, you should be able to login with

domain\login

This resolved my issue right away.